Unity LevelPlay - Could not find com.ironsource.adapters:unityadsadapter
Installed Unity levelPlay Ad Mediation via Package Manager into an empty project. Using 2022.3.34f1. Got totally headache. Even in an empty project, building into an Android device not working properly, getting the error below from gradle. Seems like cannot request to the url, getting 404. How can I solve this error?
Execution failed for task ':launcher:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':launcher:releaseRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.ironsource.adapters:unityadsadapter:4.3.40.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/ironsource/adapters/unityadsadapter/4.3.40/unityadsadapter-4.3.40.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/ironsource/adapters/unityadsadapter/4.3.40/unityadsadapter-4.3.40.pom
       - file:/C:/Users/Bermuda/Documents/buttonpush/Library/Bee/Android/Prj/IL2CPP/Gradle/unityLibrary/libs/unityadsadapter-4.3.40.jar
       - file:/C:/Users/Bermuda/Documents/buttonpush/Library/Bee/Android/Prj/IL2CPP/Gradle/unityLibrary/libs/unityadsadapter.jar
     Required by:
         project :launcher > project :unityLibrary
   > Could not find com.ironsource.sdk:mediationsdk:8.1.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/ironsource/sdk/mediationsdk/8.1.0/mediationsdk-8.1.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/ironsource/sdk/mediationsdk/8.1.0/mediationsdk-8.1.0.pom
       - file:/C:/Users/Bermuda/Documents/buttonpush/Library/Bee/Android/Prj/IL2CPP/Gradle/unityLibrary/libs/mediationsdk-8.1.0.jar
       - file:/C:/Users/Bermuda/Documents/buttonpush/Library/Bee/Android/Prj/IL2CPP/Gradle/unityLibrary/libs/mediationsdk.jar
     Required by:
         project :launcher > project :unityLibrary
   > Could not find com.ironsource:adqualitysdk:7.20.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/ironsource/adqualitysdk/7.20.1/adqualitysdk-7.20.1.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/ironsource/adqualitysdk/7.20.1/adqualitysdk-7.20.1.pom
       - file:/C:/Users/Bermuda/Documents/buttonpush/Library/Bee/Android/Prj/IL2CPP/Gradle/unityLibrary/libs/adqualitysdk-7.20.1.jar
       - file:/C:/Users/Bermuda/Documents/buttonpush/Library/Bee/Android/Prj/IL2CPP/Gradle/unityLibrary/libs/adqualitysdk.jar
     Required by:
         project :launcher > project :unityLibrary


OK. All problems solved. Problem was MobileDependencyResolver. Unity's Package Manager or ironSource's unitypackage installing this resolver while you installed mediation plugin. I removed MobileDependencyResolver and used Google's External Dependency Resolver and problems gone.
